project.pbxproj and Git / Github
I use git as VCS and XCODE to make KMP projects. Should I commit/push changes of project.pbxproj to Github? Is it necessary? What are the consequences? Is there a possibility if I dont do that, some file is not sent/ not recognised by IDEs or VCS.

Yes, you should include it. The project file tells Xcode which files comprise the iOS app.
However, I see that the question is tagged kotlin-multiplatform. If this is indeed a KMP project, you probably want to initialize the git repository in the outermost directory of the project (the one containing gradlew). As long as you don't explicitly ignore the Xcode project file, it will be included.

The git repo is there where you mentioned. I am asking that If I just change parts in the android Part, lets say some new screens are added. Then should that project.pbxproj file should be updated? I did not change anything in the ios part yet ut changed.

If you're not sure, try running the iOS project to ensure the project file hasn't been corrupted. As long as it still works, I'd include the changes.
